# Can REST only be implemented using HTTP or can we also use something else as well?

Tags: rest, http

I understand that REST is an architectural style and REST API's are HTTP requests.
So can REST only be implemented using HTTP or can we also use some others as well?

If yes any examples please.

Answer (score 2):

[REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm) is an architectural style as you mentioned. As such any architecture that conforms to its constraints implements REST *in theory*.

In practice implementing such a system from scratch is really complicated as it involves a lot of parts which need to conform to a lot of requirements. So I can't name you any alternatives which can be considered REST conform.

Also, if you are using URIs you are not constrained to HTTP, as URIs support a plethora of protocols. All of which should be supported by any client in which the resource identifier is a URI.

It is also important to mention, that most so called "REST APIs" do ***not*** conform to the requirements laid out by Mr. Fielding. And I don't mean in a nitpick-y way, I mean they just ignore it almost completely. Anything with OpenAPI/Swagger or just using the global `application/json` mediatype for example does not conform. ([Here are some more easy to spot conflicts with REST](https://javadevguy.wordpress.com/2017/12/01/5-signs-that-your-rest-api-isnt-restful/))

What I mean is, I couldn't give you a good example of REST conform "API"s based on HTTP either. (Except for the good old browser-server-html stuff).